# SQLalchemy how do I query from another table based on the dates from another table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to query the number of access attempts, failed and success, on a daily basis. These are the tables I have created.

```
class SystemLog(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'SystemLog'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Date = Column(Text)
    Time = Column(Text)
    PID = Column(Integer)
    Message = Column(Text)


class Messages(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Messages'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Message = Column(Text)
    AccessType = Column(Text)
    IP = Column(Integer)
```

What I've tried:

```
test = session.query(SystemLog.Date, Messages.AccessType, func.count(Messages.AccessType))\
        .join(Messages).filter(SystemLog.ID==Messages.ID)\
        .group_by(SystemLog.Date, Messages.AccessType).all()
```

How a SystemLog row looks like:
[image]

How a Messages row looks like:

[image]

But this gives me an error saying i need to use an ON clause. There are a few things I am unsure about as well. Are my tables created correctly and how do I do a join?

That being said, I cannot put all the columns into 1 table. At the very least, AccessType and IP has to be on a separate table and Date, Time, PID and Message have to be in 1 table.

Comment: The structure of the data is not very clear.  What's the relationship between a `SystemLog` entry and a `Message` entry?  Onr to one?  One to many? Many to one? Many to many?

Comment: One to one I believe. Basically it was take from an excel file where the columns are
Date, Time, PID, Message, AccessType, IP

All the data is in one row

Comment: What's the link between the two table?  That is, which column in `SystemLog` points to a specific row in `Message` (or the other way around)?

Comment: That's the part I'm not too sure. I felt something was wrong there that's why I think my tables are created wrongly but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. But my guess is the message columns are whats linking them

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show the data for a `SystemLog` row and its corresponding `MessageRow` please?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant but i added some graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information in the comments:

- that there is a one-to-one relationship between the tables
- that the relationship between the two is that the contents of the `message` column in related rows is identical (implying each message is unique)

the query would look like this:

```
test = session.query(SystemLog.Date, Messages.AccessType, func.count(Messages.AccessType))\
              .join(Messages, SystemLog.message == Messages.message)\
              .group_by(SystemLog.Date, Messages.AccessType).all()
```

As far as the tables are concerned, I'd try to use more specific data types, for example `Date` should be a `sqlalchemy.Date` or `sqlachemy.DateTime`.  And joining on a long string like `message` could be slow, ideally you'd join on an integer value.

Comment: Thanks man! You're a lifesaver! I realized that i could have joined on ID as well and that made it much faster